# How to get correct DPI on System.Drawing.Graphics in a Per-Monitor DPI aware app?

Tags: c#, winforms, dpi

I'm running a .NET desktop app in Per-Monitor v2 DPI Aware mode. Painting WinForms parts of the UI correctly requires that all painters know the current DPI value. High-level painters can get it from the `HWND`, that's a working solution. However, lower level painters only have a GDI+ `System.Drawing.Graphics` object.

I'm struggling with making `System.Drawing.Graphics` tell the correct DPI. Now I'm seeing the SYSTEM-level DPI on it regardless of the current DPI of its `HWND`. Its `DpiX`/`DpiY` properties are read-only, so they have to be affected indirectly.

`Graphics` has two basic ways of how it can be created for a control, either with its `HWND`, or an `HDC` over it (which might be coming from `::GetDC` or `::BeginPaint` or even `WM_PAINT` args). Either way it only has the SYSTEM DPI value, and not the per-monitor aware one. It would probably work to make a `Bitmap`, configure it appropriately and paint into that first, then blit onto the control, but that's not too neat nor optimal.

So: I'm seeing a good per-monitor-aware DPI for an `HWND` of a WinForms control, I want to see the same nice value on the `Graphics` object `DpiX`/`DpiY` properties over that control, is there a way?

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55556061/10128127 . There is mentioned the solution how to get the actual DPI scale factor

Comment: Thanks, but that answer is much outdated (it gets DPI for `GetDC(NULL)`, which won't be correct for an app running on multiple monitors or especially in Mixed DPI Hosting Behavior mode). Anyway I have ways to get DPI of a certain `HWND`, but I want a `Graphics` object correctly initialized with that DPI and telling it out to all the parties. If some painter only has a `Graphics` and no `HWND` then there's no good way to get the DPI. And wrong DPI values on `Graphics` would be misleading.

Comment: Did  you ever find a good way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

There should now way. To show a form on two monitors, you have to create 2 instances. To load a graphic/image into both forms you need only one instance of this graphic. 
A graphic is independent of your monitors and internal it doesn't need it (only a collection of pixel).

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see how this text is any relevant to the question.

Comment: Sorry for my answer! I completely misunderstood your question first. I take a deeper look into v2 DPI Aware, interesting stuff. But I found only one way to get correct DPI values: the new `Control.DeviceDpi` Property. If you reflect this code, you find a DpiHelper class who uses `GetDeviceCaps` and DC with unsafe calls. Could be helpful if you can't call the control properties directly.

Comment: Yep I can get the DPI, I cannot make it get into `Graphics` `DpiX` and `DpiY` properties so that whoever reads that from it while painting would not be using wrong values. Sooner or later somebody uses those properties and gets the UI distorted. Which you won't notice under normal conditions (because you'd have the same DPI all around), only when you remote desktop into the box or attach a monitor with another pixel density.

Comment: If you liked reading about PMv2, you might want to go deeper and read about `DPI_HOSTING_BEHAVIOR_MIXED`. That's where it gets really weird. Especially the part where you can plug SYSTEM into PMv2 but if you try it the other way around then pieces of your UI fall off.